# Adding a print dijit in jQuery Dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dojo, dialog

I'm trying to add a esri print dijit to a dialog box when the user clicks a link.  The issue I'm having is the an error is being thrown such as "can not call method toLowerCase undefined.  I'm not sure what is happening or why this is happening.  When I comment out the printInfo then the map and legend render fine.  Soon as I try to put that back in the code the to lower case method of undefined error is called and i'm stuck

Here I'm setting up my map then calling the print dijit

```
    function init(type, vid) {        

    map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
        basemap: "gray",
        sliderStyle: "large",
        center: [-95.625, 39.243],
        nav: false,
        logo: false,
        zoom: 7
    });//end base map

    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", function () {
        console.log("base and feature layers added");
        $(document).ready();
    });  //end dojo.connect

    var upDateEnd = dojo.connect(fl, "onUpdateEnd", function () {
        dojo.disconnect(upDateEnd);

        var printInfo = esri.request({
            "url": app.printUrl,
            "content": { "f": "json" }
        });
        printInfo.then(handlePrintInfo, handleError);
    });//end update       

    drawFeatureLayer();               
}//end init function
```

Here is where i call the open dialog it opens the map div and also shows the hidden legend for the map

```
    function openBox(v) {
    $("#mapDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 900,
        title: "Map Profile"
    });

    $("#mapDiv").dialog("open");
    $("#legend").show();              
}//end open box
```

Here is the HTML for the map that is opened:

```
<div id="maps" >
<div id="mapDiv" style="height:550px; width:475px; display:block;">

    <div id="print_button"></div>
        <div id="legend" style=" position:absolute; bottom:25px; z-index:100; display:none;" >        
            <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
                <li> 2-4</li>
                <li> 5-7</li>
                <li> 7-10</li>                                                 
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `app.printUrl` coming from? It doesn't look like anything is incorrect to me.

Comment: thats global string defined n the beginning